# How to comment code in visual-stuido more efficiently?

Tags: python, visual-studio

Hey just a quick question, how do you comment a large part of code?
If we have some code like this:

```
x = 2
print(x)
```

how would i comment it like this: (without commenting one line at a time)

```
# x = 2 
# print(x)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please remember to search before asking a new question. See [ask].

Comment: Thanks Chris and yeah i'll remeber to search next time lol

Answer (score 1):

Select the block of code that you want to comment and 
Press:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

And to uncomment the block of code press:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>